# mariabackup system file permissions

Tags: backup, mariadb, permissions, file-system

I have an instance of mariadb 10.6.7 on an Ubuntu 22.04 Server and I am trying to do backups of a specific database with mariabackup.

```
mariabackup --backup --user="my_test_user" --target-dir=/tmp/mdb_test --verbose
```

But always end up with

```
[00] 2022-11-07 06:57:13 mariabackup: Generating a list of tablespaces
[00] 2022-11-07 06:57:13 Can't open dir ./testdb
```

I followed the instructions for creating a backup user as they are shown here:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariabackup-overview/#authentication-and-privileges
The only difference is that i chose "unix socket" for authentication, in order to omit password files on the system.

The affected user 'my_test_user' is member of the mysql group.

Authentication is successful, however, mariabackup will fail with the following error:

```
[00] 2022-11-07 06:57:13 Connecting to MariaDB server host: localhost, user: my_test_user, password: not set, port: not set, socket: /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[00] 2022-11-07 06:57:13 Using server version 10.6.7-MariaDB-2ubuntu1.1
mariabackup based on MariaDB server 10.6.7-MariaDB debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
[00] 2022-11-07 06:57:13 uses posix_fadvise().
[00] 2022-11-07 06:57:13 cd to /var/lib/mysql/
[00] 2022-11-07 06:57:13 open files limit requested 0, set to 1024
[00] 2022-11-07 06:57:13 mariabackup: using the following InnoDB configuration:
[00] 2022-11-07 06:57:13 innodb_data_home_dir = 
[00] 2022-11-07 06:57:13 innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:12M:autoextend
[00] 2022-11-07 06:57:13 innodb_log_group_home_dir = ./
2022-11-07  6:57:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
[00] 2022-11-07 06:57:13 mariabackup: Generating a list of tablespaces
[00] 2022-11-07 06:57:13 Can't open dir ./testdb
[00] 2022-11-07 06:57:13 merror: xb_load_tablespaces() failed with error Generic error.
```

I can see that the cd to the default datadir is ok, however the database directory cannot be accessed.
This is plausible, as /var/liq/mysql/testdb has 700 permissions, so no permissions for group at all. For all I can see, this is the default permission for mysql/mariadb files and folders.
I tried to run as mysql

```
mariabackup --backup --user="mysql" --target-dir=/tmp/mdb_test --verbose
```

but this also fails for various reasons (no password, no login shell etc.; I guess the mysql user is not meant to be used that way, so...).

Now the official mariadb/mariabackup docs say
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariabackup-overview/#file-system-permissions

> Mariabackup has to read MariaDB's files from the file system.
> Therefore, when you run Mariabackup as a specific operating system
> user, you should ensure that user account has sufficient permissions
> to read those files.
>
> If you are using Linux and if you installed MariaDB with a package
> manager, then MariaDB's files will probably be owned by the mysql user
> and the mysql group.

Now I wonder how this can be done "the right way".
I have found this https://mariadb.com/kb/en/specifying-permissions-for-schema-data-directories-and-tables/ on the mariadb docs and have already exported the umask_dir=750 variable and restarted the server, but that didn't help so far, still getting the same error.

Maybe someone can help me out on what I am missing. If I change permissions on the testdb directory to 750, everything works fine, but I fear it's not a good idea to to that in a productive scenario.

Any hints are very welcome

Answer (score 1):

> however the database directory cannot be accessed. This is plausible, as /var/liq/mysql/testdb has 700 permissions, so no permissions for group at all.

Yes, `mariabackup` requires access to the physical on disk files, so `g+rX` are needed on directories and files.

> exported the umask_dir=750 variable and restarted the server, but that didn't help so far, still getting the same error.

Only affects new directories/databases. And note the systemd exception.

> If I change permissions on the testdb directory to 750, everything works fine, but I fear it's not a good idea to to that in a productive scenario.

If the `my_test_user` is the only one with a `mysql` group then its harmless.

Alternately make `mysql@localhost` the "unix socket" authenticated user and run the backup as that user. Then the user file/directory permissions are already correct.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation.

I was also thinking to make "mysql" the user to execute the backup, and already granted the required privileges, but it's not per se possible to run this as the mysql user.

mysql:x:123:131:MySQL Server,,,:/nonexistent:/bin/false

no home directory and if I'm right, /bin/false prevents login for that user.
So I guess I'll stick to changing the permissions manually and set the umask (I've also tried the systemd way, it's an ubuntu, so no way around it I guess...) for future DBs.